# Get all feasible solutions with SCIP

Tags: scipy, scipy-optimize, scip, scipy-optimize-minimize, scipy-spatial

How do I get all feasible solutions with scip? I already know something through the web "https://www.scipopt.org/doc/html/COUNTER.php". But I've learned that I only get the solutions by detected. I can't get all solutions if the feasible solutions are not be detected. So how can I set parameters to avoid the feasible solution be cut? Or how can I get all feasible solutions? Please feel free to contact me if you need any additional information.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think you already have the right ressource. You get the feasible solutions as specified exactly at the link you posted. Make sure to turn off presolving if you want all solutions to the original problem (as presolving might eliminate some non-optimal solutions, e.g. by redcost fixing)

Comment: min -x-y
   s.t. x + y <= 2
   x,y >= 0,INTEGER       I want get all feasible solutions.  I want these solutions, such as x=0,y=0; x =0,y=1;  x=0,y=2; x=1,y=0; x=1,y=1;x=2,y=0;